# Copy image CSS from another website

Tags: html, css

I have a website: http://marekzurek.hekko24.pl 
I'm trying to copy the testimonial photo effect found on this website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Jqd.png

What should I add to my css to make the image with the class "client-pic" round and small?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<div class="testimonial-list">
<!-- START SINGLE TESTIMONIAL DESIGN AREA -->
<div class="single-testimonial text-center">
<img src="http://1stwebcoder.co m/themes/nexus/nexus/images/client.jpg" alt="client" class="client-pic">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<h2>mark jukarbarg</h2>
<h3>CEO facebook</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read this:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it ..........

Comment: This comment my be off-topic, but could you make a codepen/fiddle or smth if that typing effect on your page? ;) That's pretty neat.

Comment: Add soething what you have tried and what error you got? share working code.

Comment: I've edited post. Please check now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the css you want to add to make that photo round and small

```
.client-pic {
  width: 80px; 
  height: 80px; 
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Tip for the future, if you want to scrape code off of other websites, use inspect element browser feature to get to css used on any specific element.